# React Cannot read property 'value' of undefined with option element

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, jsx

I have an array that looks like this..

```
OrchardSite > Array(16) > 0: {blocks: Array (3), name: "asdasd", code: "R101A"}
                          1: {blocks: Array (7), name: "dasdas", code: "R555"}
```

Each site has a different amount of blocks, When I select a Site, I want to see the selected value, eg if I select R101A, It should only have 3 blocks, this is something I'll implement later. Right now I can't even read the value of the selected element, and this is what I need help with..

```
setOrchard = (event) => {
  const orchardId = event.target.value;
  console.log("orchardID", orchardId)
   if (orchardId.length > 0) {
      if (!this.props.metadata.OrchardSites[parseInt(orchardId)].blocks) 
          this.props.metadata.orchardSites[parseInt(orchardId)].blocks = []
            console.log("SetttingOrchardLocation", this.props.metadata.orchardSites)
            this.setState({ orchardId: orchardId, block: null, area: null, row: null, site: Object.assign({}, this.props.metadata.orchardSites[parseInt(orchardId)]) })
            console.log("Testing OrchardId", this.props.metadata.orchardSites[parseInt(orchardId)])
        // parseInt to get access to the array index, (Maybe I need to .ToString() somewhere?
    }
}
```

in my render I have this..

```
const orchardId: string = (this.state as any).orchardId.toString()
```

And my JSX looks like this

```
<select className="input-field-slider dropdown w-select" onChange={() => this.setOrchard(orchardId)}>
<option>All Sites</option>
{orchardSites
    .map((orchardSite, i) => (
        <option key={i} value={orchardSite.code}>
            {orchardSite.code + " " + orchardSite.name}
        </option>
    ))}
```

Every time I change the option in my dropdown, my function fires and gives me an updated Orchard, well thats the idea Anyway..

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Instead I'm greeted with this, each time I change the option..

Comment: you're calling setOrchard like `this.setOrchard(orchardId)` ... therefore, in `setOrchard = (event)` the value of `event` will be `orchardId` not an actual event with a `target` etc - I don't know reactjs, (which is why I'm commenting not answering) but it seems you may want to do `onChange={e=> this.setOrchard(e)}` ... perhaps

Comment: @JaromandaX that worked, however blocks is undefined..How can I get access to that array?

Comment: Sorry, no idea - is orchardId the right value at that point in the code?

Comment: Yup, correct value

Comment: well, the problem is completely different now and beyond my expertise